# Using azure custom api giving error with POST

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure web service with custom api with POST as following :

```
 mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "Your web service",
                "niHVXXnRXOGVGnvEMvImMIdgnraflH99",
                this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());
 loadData();

 private void loadData() {
    ArrayList<Pair<String ,String>> bodyParams = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("username","xyz@gmail.com"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("password","qwertyuiop"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("displayname","your name"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("phonenumber","9745893297"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("phoneIMEI","356938035643809"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("isindividualgroup","false"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("firmName",""));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("address1",""));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("phone1",""));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("city","Pune"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("state","Maharashtra"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("countryId","2"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("zipCode",""));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("offeringiD","1004bca1-d45f-4da5-8608-199f380b6725"));
    bodyParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("numberOfLicense","0"));


    mClient.invokeApi("CustomRegistration", null, "POST", null, bodyParams, new ServiceFilterResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ServiceFilterResponse response, Exception exception) {
            if(exception!= null)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("RESPONSE : " + response.getContent());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

and when I run it on device its giving an error like following:

```
com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {"$id":"1","message":"An error has occurred."}
```

can anyone tell what is the problem in this ?
I am very sure that URL is correct and also parameters are correct but not getting the response.
Please help me.

Comment: Use fiddler to determine whether the request is good, or something like Postman to see the actual error.  It's probably in your custom API code, which you did not post.  You can also check the diagnostic logs on the Azure side for more information usually.  Anything logged to the console in your service will be captured in the diagnostic logs.

Comment: Please see this wiki for some other troubleshooting instructions: [https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!)